# $\Omega_{r}$ from WMAP results?

Tags: cosmology, specific-reference, radiation, cosmic-microwave-background

To do some Friedmann-Lemaître cosmology calculations, I would like to know an estimation of $\Omega_{r_0}$ ($\Omega$ radiation today). WMAP 7 give estimation of $\Omega_{b}$, $\Omega_{c}$ and $\Omega_{\Lambda}$ but nothing about $\Omega_{r}$ : http://lambda.gsfc.nasa.gov/product/map/dr4/best_params.cfm
Where can I find the best value of $\Omega_{r}$ available today ?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried looking at these: http://arxiv.org/find/astro-ph/1/au:+Larson_D/0/1/0/all/0/1  (Seven year analysis of WMAP data)?

Comment: Perfect. I didn't know that $z_{eq}$ was the redshift of matter-radiation equality. After some calculation for a Friedmannian Universe, we can find that $\Omega_{r_0} = \frac{\Omega_{m_0}}{1+z_{eq}} \approx \frac{0.272}{1+3232} \approx 8.413 \times 10^{-5}$

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

According to [Hyperphysics](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/astro/denpar.html) $\Omega_{rel} = 8.24 \times 10^{-5}$. The article references Carroll, Bradley W. and Ostlie, Dale A., An Introduction to Modern Astrophysics. I don't have this book so I can't comment on how authoritative this figure is.