# Does charge bend spacetime like mass?

Tags: electromagnetism, general-relativity, spacetime, curvature, geometry

1. Does charge bend spacetime like mass?

I'm not asking if electromagnetic forces can be described geometrically, but if EM fields could correspond to particular curvatures of spacetime, like gravity which arises from the spacetime bending due to the stress-energy tensor.

2. Is it true in the three spacial dimensions we observe?
3. Is it plausible in other dimensions (for example the fourth dimensions of the Kaluza-Klein theory)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is spacetime curved by mass but not charge?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/111761/)

Comment: See also [Do electromagnetic fields gravitate?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/90507/do-electromagnetic-fields-gravitate)

Answer (score 3):

Charge, giving rise to EM fields (or any other kind of field, really) does create spacetime curvature. See for instance the difference between the Schwarzschild metric and the Reissner-Nordström metric.